# Virtual USB bus using TCP

Tags: windows, usb

I have a router that a printer can be attached to to print wirelessly to. It appears that the software for Windows uses a virtual USB bus using TCP. This allows the printer to appear as if it was plugged directly into the computer.

[image: Windows device driver]

**Is it possible to create a virtual USB bus using TCP on Ubuntu or is this a custom protocol used by the router and Windows software?**

Comment: Further to my comments below - I see from your other question this is a WNDR4500. I have a DGND3700 which is quite different, but some things are the same. You might get some answers if you enable the telnet console on this device and poke around in the system, though this is quite advanced stuff, and you can break it if you're not careful.

Comment: @AlistairBuxton Thanks for the suggestion and warning, but it's my dad's router, so I don't want to risk breaking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is potentially a custom/proprietary protocol used by your router and the software designed by the manufacturer.

However, USB over IP is a thing and it can be used on Ubuntu. Assuming your router is using the standard USB over IP and not a custom protocol, [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-usb-over-ip-server-and-client-with-ubuntu-10.04-p2) page (paraphrased below for anyone who finds this through google) should help you set it up.

1. Install usbip

   `sudo apt-get install usbip`
2. Load the vhci-hcd kernel module

   `modprobe vhci-hcd`
3. Check if it really got loaded

   `lsmod | grep vhci_hcd`

   (Your out should be similar to below)

   ```
   root@client1:~# lsmod | grep vhci_hcd
   vhci_hcd               19800  0
   usbip_common_mod       13605  1 vhci_hcd
   root@client1:~#
   ```
4. (optional) Add module to load on boot

   `sudo echo vhci-hcd >> /etc/modules`
5. Connect to the server (your router) and get a list of devices.

   `usbip -l serverip`

   Replace `serverip` with the IP address of your router.

   Example output:

   ```
   root@client1:~# usbip -l 192.168.0.100
   - 192.168.0.100
        1-1: SanDisk Corp. : Cruzer Micro Flash Drive (0781:5151)
           : /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.2/usb1/1-1
           : (Defined at Interface level) (00/00/00)
           :  0 - Mass Storage / SCSI / Bulk (Zip) (08/06/50)
   ```

   Note the designation of the USB device you want to use (1-1 in this example).
6. Attach the remote device to the local computer.

   ```
   usbip -a serverip designation
   ```

   e.g.

   ```
   usbip -a 192.168.12.34 1-1
   ```

   The remote device should now be attached locally to your computer. You should see it listed if you execute `lsusb` from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I get to the `usbip -l 192.168.1.1` part, I get this message `- 192.168.1.1 failed`. When I go to the router's IP address in a web browser, I'm prompted for the user name and password to administer the router. Is this the reason the command is failing or is it because the device doesn't support the standard protocol?

Comment: I came across [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/226136/how-to-simulate-a-usb-plug). Would [the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/usbip/+bug/898003) it mentions affect me?

Comment: With regards 'proprietary protocols' - I would say it is unlikely. Many of the high-end routers which have features like this run Linux inside so there is a good chance it uses usbip. Telling us the make of router might help.

Comment: And yes, looks like that bug may affect you.

Comment: I just tried the instructions given above. No only did it not work, it also hard locked my machine a couple of seconds later.